# using unbound methods in another python class

Tags: python, methods

I have an unbound method  as `<unbound method foo.ops>`,  i would like to use the same method with another class. take an example

```
class foo2(object):
  pass

foo2.ops = foo.ops
```

however

```
obj = foo2()
obj.ops()

raises TypeError: unbound method ops() must be called with foo instance as first argument (got nothing instead)
```

Comment: Take the hint.  Don't do this.  You have inheritance.  Use inheritance for this.  Not magic.

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you want to add the same method to several unrelated classes (e.g. doing AOP), don't copy an unbound method from one of them. Instead, define a plain function and assign it as a method to every class.

Usually a better way to do it is a mixin (using plain inheritance) or a metaclass (class decorator syntax is neat).

If you're hell-bound to steal a method from a class (e.g. one you don't control), you can extract it from the 'unbound method' wrapper: `foo2.ops.im_func`; it's a plain function and you can assign it as a method to another class.

Comment: Could you provide an example using a mixin or a metaclass?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to implement 'class methods', you should call it accordingly, whithout object instance

```
class foo:
    @staticmethod
    def ops(name):
        print "Hi there",name

foo.ops("Peter")

class foo2:
    pass

foo2.ops = staticmethod(foo.ops)

foo2.ops('aa')
```

(copy-pasted from http://code.activestate.com/recipes/52304-static-methods-aka-class-methods-in-python/)

if you want instance method, use inheritance

Comment: The example is more than 8 years old, you can use @staticmethod now.

Comment: but it doesn't work if we want to copy method to another class, does it?

Comment: @staticmethod does the same as Callable, but the original question needs something like: foo2.ops = staticmethod(foo.ops) S.Lott is right though, it shouldn't be used...