# Unique uses for unbound methods?

Tags: python

SO has lots of posts on unbound vs. bound methods.

- [Class method differences in Python: bound, unbound and static](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/114214/class-method-differences-in-python-bound-unbound-and-static)
- [python bound and unbound method object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13348031/python-bound-and-unbound-method-object)
- [using unbound methods in another python class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5701201/using-unbound-methods-in-another-python-class)

I understand the definition. Do unbound methods have any utility unique to this category? If so, could someone provide an example? I am not asking for a best application, simply a unique application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most obvious use case that comes to mind is for a control system. Imagine you have many players in a game where they can send you various commands across the network.. you might want to create a dict like:

```
player_commands = {
  'move'  : Player.move
  'attack': Player.attack
  ...
}
```

Then you can read the string and call the appropriate method with any Player object

`player_commands[cmd](theplayer)`

And it saves you having to have a big if/else chain like

```
if cmd == 'move':
      theplayer.move()
   elif cmd == 'attack':
      ...
```

Also since it's a dictionary you can update/edit it dynamically.